# Branch.io : Add query parameters in deep link url dynamically through code?

Tags: android, url-parameters, branch.io

I am trying to add parameters in URL which will be shared on Whatsapp, like www.abc.com/{parameter}/{parameter}.

I have tried adding control parameters in link properties with "$deeplink_path" key, but nothing is happening.

```
 LinkProperties lp = new LinkProperties()
                .setChannel("whatsapp")
                .setFeature("sharing")
                .setCampaign("content 123 launch")
                .setStage("new user")
            .addControlParameter("$deeplink_path","user-123);
```

My link is still coming like the same: www.abc.com and not appending "user-123" with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter $deeplink_path is actually used as a deep link parameter. It is not used to create links with a specific alias.

To create a link with a certain alias, you'll need to add '.setAlias("user-123")' which should create a link ex. www.abc.com/user-123.

If you have additional questions please write into support@branch.io and we would be glad to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding query params programmatically is super-easy - you just append the params like you would to any other http link. For example:

```
https://superapp.app.link/alias?param1=first&param2=second
```

Here:

- `https://superapp.app.link/alias` is the Quick Link created through the dashboard,
- `alias` is the alias, generated randomly by branch.io or entered manually by yourself, both during link creation on the dashboard
- `param1` and `param2` are parameters, and `first` and `second` are their respective values.

Note: if you added some extra Link Data (parameters) during Quick Link creation on the dashboard, you would get those params together with the query params from the deep link itself.